# PHP PayPal Subscriptions

Tags: php

I'm looking for any way of using the PayPal IPN to create subscriptions and update my Databases.

I know it's a bit of a vague question but any script/class that will create a subscription and allow me to do anything automated on payment would be great.

I've been playing around with the PayPal IPN for a while now but can't seem to get anything to work for subscriptions.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPN is only used for notifications, not to issue commands. You need to either look into their SOAP API or their NVP API.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_soap_PayPalSOAPAPIArchitecture

You might want to look through their forum for examples like this (there is probably tons of other premade classes/scripts):

https://www.x.com/thread/36523